# How to set the read channel buffer size when using readUTF8Line in Ktor

Tags: kotlin, http, stream, jvm, ktor

I am using Ktor 2.3.2 in JVM and I am receiving a HTTP response as a stream from a server which contains lines (separated by LF).

I already have following code:

```kotlin
httpClient.preparePost("/some/api/endpoint".apiUrl) {
    contentType(ContentType.Application.Json)
    setBody("test")
}.execute {
    val channel: ByteReadChannel = it.body()
    var line: String?
    do {
        line = channel.readUTF8Line()
        if (line != null) {
            // Do stuff with this line
        }
    }  while (line != null)
}
```

The HTTP client variable in question is constructed in following way:

```kotlin
    val httpClient = HttpClient(Java) {
        install(ContentNegotiation) {
            json(Json { ignoreUnknownKeys = true })
        }
        install(ContentEncoding) {
            gzip(1.0f)
            deflate(0.6f)
            identity(0.1f)
        }
        install(HttpRequestRetry) {
            retryOnExceptionIf(3) { b, throwable ->
                logger.warn("Warning: Exception ${throwable::class.simpleName} for ${b.url.buildString()}")
                throwable.printStack()
                throwable.hasCause<HttpRequestTimeoutException>()
            }
            retryOnExceptionIf(100) { b, throwable ->
                logger.warn("Warning: Exception ${throwable::class.simpleName} for ${b.url.buildString()}")
                throwable.printStack()
                throwable.hasCause<IOException>()
            }
            constantDelay(200, 1000)
        }
        // Enable request timeouts:
        //install(HttpTimeout)
        install(HttpSend) {
            maxSendCount = 1000
        }
        // Enable request logging:
        //install(Logging)
        expectSuccess = true
        engine {
            threadsCount = 1
        }
    }.apply {
        plugin(HttpSend).intercept { request ->
            onHttpRequest(request)
        }
    }
```

It seems like the `channel: ByteReadChannel` is buffered, so the lines are coming in in batches. I would like to make this channel unbuffered or at least reduce the buffer size so that I can act on the incoming lines more frequently.

Is there a way to do that using Ktor or do I have to use a different HTTP client?

Comment: Unfortunately, there is no way of changing the channel's capacity.

Comment: Why? Is it hardcoded?

Comment: Looks like maybe this is still being worked on: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KTOR-505/Add-Server-sent-events-SSE-plugin-for-client-and-support-for-OkHttp-engine#focus=Comments-27-8407801.0-0

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `ByteReadChannel.consumeEachBufferRange` that runs a lambda that you pass to it on every buffer of the channel

Comment: Your ansswer could be improved by adding a code snippet that exemplifies the use of the API you are suggesting.

Comment: But how do I configure the size of said buffer? I need to process the response line-by-line and would like to be able to process the lines immediately or at least more frequently as they come in.